# Cannot connect to the configuration database

Tags: sql-server, configuration, database-connection

I don't really know what to do. I was trying to get some bcs working, and because they were not, I've decided to restart the server.

After it restarted I was unable to go on any site / page or on the central administration. I had this message :

> [WebPartPageUserException: Cannot connect to the configuration
>   database Error]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.EnsureInitialize(HttpRequest
>   request) +740
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.BeginRequestHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea) +164
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

I first tried to do a open sql server manager, and discovered that I couldn't connect to sql server neither. After some researches I found how to restart sql server manager. And know it's okay, I can connect to sql server via sql server manager. But I still can't connect to my SharePoint server via browser.

I tried to do an iisreset, but it doesn't work. 
So if you have any idea on how I could resolve this issue, I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but I had a problem with sql server which only accepted two connections at the same time. I increased this number and it was ok :)

Comment: And how have you increased this number?

Comment: May I know how?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Since your SQL Server Service apparently went down as well, it seems the issue is less about SharePoint and something more systemic.

Ideas:
- check the UMLS and diagnostics logs in the SharePoint hive.There, you should find the source or details of your error.
- go into your Windows Services. (Adminstrative Tools -> Services). Check to see that your SQL Server Service is started. You may want to restart it (right click,stop, start). Also, check your SharePoint Services,  stop and start them as well. then go back into CA.
- if you cant get into CA then, open a cmd prompt with admin privileges, and run an iisreset. let me know.